# Which groups/time periods to compare in staggered Difference in Difference (DiD) with unit and time fixed effect logistic regression model?

Tags: logistic, fixed-effects-model, difference-in-difference, logic

I am trying to build a logistic regression with staggered DiD (for not yet treated) that incoporates unit and time fixed effect.

I am stuck with the logic of building the model as I am trying to understand which time periods should be compared across the two groups.
My context is project funding success and I have two groups of countries: Group 1 consist of countries started to have to Covid during January 2020 and group 2 (the not yet treated) are countries that started to have Covid from February 2020 to March 2020.

The two groups are represented in four time periods:
Time 0 (before January 2020): Before Covid (where the two groups are not treated).
Time 1 (beginning January 2020 to end of January 2020): Where group 1 is treated but not groups 2.
Time 2 (March 2020 and April 2020): Where group 1 is already treated and group 2 is being treated.
Time 3 (after April 2020): Both group 1 and group 2 are treated.

In building the logistic model I am confused regarding:

1. Whether I should exclude data related to time 0 from the dataset?
2. Whether I should exclude data related to time 3 from the dataset?
3. Which group/time combination I should compare to test the effect of Covid on the relationship between the binary dependent variable and the independent variables?